# How to navigate back after clicking on a link?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping, click

I'm very new to work with IE in vba so it is hard for me sometimes to rectify any mistake I make while writing any code to scrape data from web. I've written some code to click on each video links out of 20 links under the caption `Microsoft computer training videos` available in it's front page. I expect to click each links then navigate back and repeat the process until all the links are clicked. The class names and tag names I've defined in my scraper is accurate. All i need to do is perform the process in the right way. At this moment my scraper is clicking the last link of the 20 links and get stuck there where it reaches but don't navigate back.

This is what I've written so far.

```
Sub clicking_links()

    Const surl As String = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, iedoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate surl
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set iedoc = IE.document
    End With

    For Each posts In iedoc.getElementsByClassName("woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle")
        posts.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
    Next posts

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just use `IE.navigate surl` after `Next posts`?

Comment: @Victor K  ,I don't understand your logic of using `IE.navigate surl` after the loop cause when looping is done it is nowhere to go without getting back to `surl` page.

Comment: Well, you said you want it to navigate back after the loop. I Interpreted that as navigate to the start. Where would you like it go after the loop then?

Comment: It only clicks the last link and gets stuck there out of 20 not all through 20.

Comment: try to wait until load after each click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub clicking_links()

    Const surl As String = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
    Dim newurl as String
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, iedoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object
    Dim t As Long, i As Long

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate surl
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set iedoc = .document

        For Each posts In iedoc.getElementsByClassName("woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle")
            t = t + 1 'count the number of posts
        Next posts

        For i = 1 To t
            Debug.Print i
            newurl = iedoc.getElementsByClassName("woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle")(i - 1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
            Debug.Print newurl

            .navigate newurl
            Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
            Set iedoc = .document
            'here do your stuff within the new url

            .navigate surl 'back to old url
            Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
            Set iedoc = .document
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No way, Tehscript!!! It works like magic. I'm not going to give you any chance to rest. In your spare time please follow this link as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682740/avoiding-hardcoded-delay-and-creating-conditional-statement-to-shake-off-error