# Send Keys back to prev page

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Currently working with VBA Excel and IE, and I want to send keys after running macro is to finalize it by going back to the previous page.

This is what I have so far, but seems like not working.

```
Application.SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719010/11167163) might help you

Comment: What are you actually doing just before the code line you show. Please make it a [mre]. Why do you think that `{BACKSPACE}` would be the solution (does hitting the BS key do what you expect )?

Comment: I have page with the field set that was hide and once I click a dropdown selection it displays the hidden fieldset. The problem is when I use a selectedindex vba formula, it does select the dropdown but not showing the fieldset. Now when I hit a go button then press back the selection is there and the fieldset shows.

Comment: According to your description, I created a simple demo to test it, and it can go back to previous page normally. This is [my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EgVk.png). As already mentioned, please provide code that can reproduce the problem. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Are you looking for Application.SendKeys ("%{Left}") , to do Alt-Left (Previous Page) ?